# How to call a macro, to Convert Accented Characters to Regular, that does not appear in the list?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to replace accented characters with regular characters.

When I try to run the macro it doesn't appear in the list.

```
Option Explicit

'-- Add more chars to these 2 string as you want
'-- You may have problem with unicode chars that has code > 255
'-- such as some Vietnamese characters that are outside of ASCII code (0-255)
Const AccChars = "ŠŽšžŸÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿ"
Const RegChars = "SZszYAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnooooouuuuyy"

Sub StripAccent(aRange As Range)
'-- Usage: StripAccent Sheet1.Range("A1:C20")
Dim A As String * 1
Dim B As String * 1
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To Len(AccChars)
A = Mid(AccChars, i, 1)
B = Mid(RegChars, i, 1)
aRange.Replace What:=A, _
Replacement:=B, _
LookAt:=xlPart, _
MatchCase:=True
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I tested it in both 2007 and 2010 and it works perfectly. What exactly is not working?

Comment: I do not see the option to run the macro in my macros list. The macro name is not appearing in the list to select. I have macros enabled and I have a bunch of others I use so I do not understand why it's not showing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> > > I do not see the option to run the macro in my macros list. The macro name is not appearing in the list to select. I have macros enabled and I have a bunch of others I use so I do not understand why it's not showing. – BvilleBullet 4 mins ago

Please see the comment in the above code.

> > > '-- Usage: StripAccent Sheet1.Range("A1:C20")

You have to call it like this

```
Option Explicit

'-- Add more chars to these 2 string as you want
'-- You may have problem with unicode chars that has code > 255
'-- such as some Vietnamese characters that are outside of ASCII code (0-255)
Const AccChars = "ŠŽšžŸÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿ"
Const RegChars = "SZszYAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnooooouuuuyy"

'~~> This is how you have to call it. Now You can see the macro "Sample" in the list
Sub Sample()
    StripAccent Sheet1.Range("A1:C20")
End Sub

Sub StripAccent(aRange As Range)
    '-- Usage: StripAccent Sheet1.Range("A1:C20")
    Dim A As String * 1
    Dim B As String * 1
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To Len(AccChars)
        A = Mid(AccChars, i, 1)
        B = Mid(RegChars, i, 1)
        aRange.Replace What:=A, _
        Replacement:=B, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, _
        MatchCase:=True
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 7):

For those who need to remove accent marks from ALL Roman characters, including extended ones like those used in Vietnamese, then follow the instructions below.

1. First, let's prepare the spreadsheet to do its VBA magic. In the Microsoft VBA editor, select Tools / References and put a checkmark next to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime". We'll need this to define a dictionary object in the subsequent steps.
2. Next, we create a global dictionary in order to map the accented characters to their unaccented equivalents. This is done when the `Workbook_Open` event is triggered so that the dictionary is only initiated once when you open the spreadsheet instead of every time you call the function. `AsciiDict` is defined as a public variable in step 3. In the "Project - VBAProject" panel, double-click on ThisWorkbook to open the workbook scope. Paste the following code there (below `Option Explicit`):

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  InitDictionary
End Sub

Sub InitDictionary()
  AsciiDict(192) = "A"
  AsciiDict(193) = "A"
  AsciiDict(194) = "A"
  AsciiDict(195) = "A"
  AsciiDict(196) = "A"
  AsciiDict(197) = "A"
  AsciiDict(199) = "C"
  AsciiDict(200) = "E"
  AsciiDict(201) = "E"
  AsciiDict(202) = "E"
  AsciiDict(203) = "E"
  AsciiDict(204) = "I"
  AsciiDict(205) = "I"
  AsciiDict(206) = "I"
  AsciiDict(207) = "I"
  AsciiDict(208) = "D"
  AsciiDict(209) = "N"
  AsciiDict(210) = "O"
  AsciiDict(211) = "O"
  AsciiDict(212) = "O"
  AsciiDict(213) = "O"
  AsciiDict(214) = "O"
  AsciiDict(217) = "U"
  AsciiDict(218) = "U"
  AsciiDict(219) = "U"
  AsciiDict(220) = "U"
  AsciiDict(221) = "Y"
  AsciiDict(224) = "a"
  AsciiDict(225) = "a"
  AsciiDict(226) = "a"
  AsciiDict(227) = "a"
  AsciiDict(228) = "a"
  AsciiDict(229) = "a"
  AsciiDict(231) = "c"
  AsciiDict(232) = "e"
  AsciiDict(233) = "e"
  AsciiDict(234) = "e"
  AsciiDict(235) = "e"
  AsciiDict(236) = "i"
  AsciiDict(237) = "i"
  AsciiDict(238) = "i"
  AsciiDict(239) = "i"
  AsciiDict(240) = "d"
  AsciiDict(241) = "n"
  AsciiDict(242) = "o"
  AsciiDict(243) = "o"
  AsciiDict(244) = "o"
  AsciiDict(245) = "o"
  AsciiDict(246) = "o"
  AsciiDict(249) = "u"
  AsciiDict(250) = "u"
  AsciiDict(251) = "u"
  AsciiDict(252) = "u"
  AsciiDict(253) = "y"
  AsciiDict(255) = "y"
  AsciiDict(352) = "S"
  AsciiDict(353) = "s"
  AsciiDict(376) = "Y"
  AsciiDict(381) = "Z"
  AsciiDict(382) = "z"
  AsciiDict(258) = "A"
  AsciiDict(259) = "a"
  AsciiDict(272) = "D"
  AsciiDict(273) = "d"
  AsciiDict(296) = "I"
  AsciiDict(297) = "i"
  AsciiDict(360) = "U"
  AsciiDict(361) = "u"
  AsciiDict(416) = "O"
  AsciiDict(417) = "o"
  AsciiDict(431) = "U"
  AsciiDict(432) = "u"
  AsciiDict(7840) = "A"
  AsciiDict(7841) = "a"
  AsciiDict(7842) = "A"
  AsciiDict(7843) = "a"
  AsciiDict(7844) = "A"
  AsciiDict(7845) = "a"
  AsciiDict(7846) = "A"
  AsciiDict(7847) = "a"
  AsciiDict(7848) = "A"
  AsciiDict(7849) = "a"
  AsciiDict(7850) = "A"
  AsciiDict(7851) = "a"
  AsciiDict(7852) = "A"
  AsciiDict(7853) = "a"
  AsciiDict(7854) = "A"
  AsciiDict(7855) = "a"
  AsciiDict(7856) = "A"
  AsciiDict(7857) = "a"
  AsciiDict(7858) = "A"
  AsciiDict(7859) = "a"
  AsciiDict(7860) = "A"
  AsciiDict(7861) = "a"
  AsciiDict(7862) = "A"
  AsciiDict(7863) = "a"
  AsciiDict(7864) = "E"
  AsciiDict(7865) = "e"
  AsciiDict(7866) = "E"
  AsciiDict(7867) = "e"
  AsciiDict(7868) = "E"
  AsciiDict(7869) = "e"
  AsciiDict(7870) = "E"
  AsciiDict(7871) = "e"
  AsciiDict(7872) = "E"
  AsciiDict(7873) = "e"
  AsciiDict(7874) = "E"
  AsciiDict(7875) = "e"
  AsciiDict(7876) = "E"
  AsciiDict(7877) = "e"
  AsciiDict(7878) = "E"
  AsciiDict(7879) = "e"
  AsciiDict(7880) = "I"
  AsciiDict(7881) = "i"
  AsciiDict(7882) = "I"
  AsciiDict(7883) = "i"
  AsciiDict(7884) = "O"
  AsciiDict(7885) = "o"
  AsciiDict(7886) = "O"
  AsciiDict(7887) = "o"
  AsciiDict(7888) = "O"
  AsciiDict(7889) = "o"
  AsciiDict(7890) = "O"
  AsciiDict(7891) = "o"
  AsciiDict(7892) = "O"
  AsciiDict(7893) = "o"
  AsciiDict(7894) = "O"
  AsciiDict(7895) = "o"
  AsciiDict(7896) = "O"
  AsciiDict(7897) = "o"
  AsciiDict(7898) = "O"
  AsciiDict(7899) = "o"
  AsciiDict(7900) = "O"
  AsciiDict(7901) = "o"
  AsciiDict(7902) = "O"
  AsciiDict(7903) = "o"
  AsciiDict(7904) = "O"
  AsciiDict(7905) = "o"
  AsciiDict(7906) = "O"
  AsciiDict(7907) = "o"
  AsciiDict(7908) = "U"
  AsciiDict(7909) = "u"
  AsciiDict(7910) = "U"
  AsciiDict(7911) = "u"
  AsciiDict(7912) = "U"
  AsciiDict(7913) = "u"
  AsciiDict(7914) = "U"
  AsciiDict(7915) = "u"
  AsciiDict(7916) = "U"
  AsciiDict(7917) = "u"
  AsciiDict(7918) = "U"
  AsciiDict(7919) = "u"
  AsciiDict(7920) = "U"
  AsciiDict(7921) = "u"
  AsciiDict(7922) = "Y"
  AsciiDict(7923) = "y"
  AsciiDict(7924) = "Y"
  AsciiDict(7925) = "y"
  AsciiDict(7926) = "Y"
  AsciiDict(7927) = "y"
  AsciiDict(7928) = "Y"
  AsciiDict(7929) = "y"
  AsciiDict(8363) = "d"
End Sub
```

3. Finally, we create a function called `StripDiacritics()` to normalize the text. In the "Project - VBAProject" panel, double-click on Modules / Module1 to open the module scope (if you don't see it, then you'll have to add it by right-clicking on ThisWorkbook and selecting Insert / Module). Paste the following code there (below `Option Explicit`):

```vb
'Dictionary initiated in Workbook_Open()
Public AsciiDict As New Scripting.Dictionary

Function StripDiacritics(Text As String) As String
  Text = Trim(Text)
  If Text = "" Then Exit Function
  Dim Char As String, _
    NormalizedText As String, _
    UnicodeCharCode As Long, _
    i As Long
  'Remove accent marks (diacritics) from text
  For i = 1 To Len(Text)
    Char = Mid(Text, i, 1)
    UnicodeCharCode = AscW(Char)
    If (UnicodeCharCode < 0) Then
      'See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/272138
      UnicodeCharCode = 65536 + UnicodeCharCode
    End If
    If AsciiDict.Exists(UnicodeCharCode) Then
      NormalizedText = NormalizedText & AsciiDict.Item(UnicodeCharCode)
    Else
      NormalizedText = NormalizedText & Char
    End If
  Next
  StripDiacritics = NormalizedText
End Function
```

4. Save and re-open the spreadsheet for the mapping dictionary to be properly initiated.

**Usage:**

`=StripDiacritics("Hermès Prêt à Porter")`
Outputs "Hermes Pret a Porter"
`=StripDiacritics("Việt Nam Textiles")`
Outputs "Viet Nam Textiles"

For those who are curious, the complete mappings can be found here: https://goo.gl/Vvn9px. The dictionary keys correspond to the Dec column.

Comment: I tried and tested it, this one works very good for Vietnamese.

Comment: This doesn't work on many Turkish charactes, such as `ğ`, `ş` and `č`. Perhaps you can update the dictionary?

Comment: For those who need to amend the dictionary with their own characters, you can make a sheet for the dictionary, put the letters to replace in column `A` and use the formula `=UNICODE(A2)` to get the codes for the letters you need to replace.

Answer (score 7):

```
Function stripAccent(Text As String) As String

    Const AccChars = "ŠŽšžŸÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿ"
    Const RegChars = "SZszYAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnooooouuuuyy"

    Dim A As String * 1
    Dim B As String * 1
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To Len(AccChars)
        A = Mid(AccChars, i, 1)
        B = Mid(RegChars, i, 1)
        Text = Replace(Text, A, B)
    Next

    stripAccent = Text

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

The function provided by @notGeek `stripAccent` worked for me except it converted lower case accented characters to uppercase non-accented characters.

This seems to be because the `Replace` function by default is case insensitive. This can be changed by adding the compare setting of `vbBinaryCompare` as below

```
Text = Replace(Text, A, B, , , vbBinaryCompare)
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean the list of macros in Macro Dialog Box ? If so, it's because the range parameters, the Macro Dialog Box will list only procedures without parameters.

Comment: OK so how can I run this code then? I ussually run the macro via the dialog box or code a button to it but it's not appearing to select.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a userForm with a refEdit and button control. 
The routine that call the form is something like:

```
Sub ShowForm()

    Dim d As dlg
    Set d = New dlg

    d.Show

    Set d = Nothing

End Sub
```

...and in the click event of the button:

```
Private Sub cmdBtn_Click()

    On Error GoTo cmdBtn_Click_Err

    Dim strRange As String
    Dim rng As Range

    strRange = refeditControl.Text

    Set rng = Range(strRange)        

    Call StripAccent(rng)        

cmdBtn_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

cmdBtn_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume cmdBtn_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

Assuming the userForm is name dlg, the button cmdBtn and the refEdit control refEditControl.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to remove special character from the string.

```
Function Remove(Str As String) As String
    Dim xChars As String
    Dim I As Long
    xChars = "/.',_#$%@!()^*&"
    For I = 1 To Len(xChars)
        Str = Replace$(Str, Mid$(xChars, I, 1), "")
    Next
    Remove = Str
End Function
```