# Search for names with accents

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to search an Excel spreadsheet for names which may include accents using normal letters?

At the moment, unless you know the precise spelling and which names have accented letters, the results are not found. The search is done via a userform textbox which filters the spreadsheet.
For instance, if I search for 'Leon', I will find forenames or surnames like 'Leonard', but I won't find 'Léoni'.

The search doesn't seem to be case sensitive, which means it can search for alternative char numbers, so I was hoping it would cope with acute and grave accents, etc.
I am using VBA through a userform to filter the results.

I don't want to resort to stripping all the accents out.

I tried this:

```vb
Dim myAltPlyr As String
myAltPlyr = "MAÇON"
Dim ChkAccent As Long
For ChkAccent = 1 To Len(myAltPlyr)
    If Asc(Mid(myAltPlyr, ChkAccent, 1)) = 138 Or Asc(Mid(myAltPlyr, ChkAccent, 1)) >= 192 Or Mid(myAltPlyr, ChkAccent, 1) = ChrW(&H10C) Then
        Select Case Asc(Mid(myAltPlyr, ChkAccent, 1))
        Case 192 To 198                      ' 7 x accented A
            Mid(myAltPlyr, ChkAccent, 1) = "A"
        Case 199                             ' 1 x Ç (C with cedilla)
            Mid(myAltPlyr, ChkAccent, 1) = "C"
        Case 200 To 203                      ' 4 x accented E
            Mid(myAltPlyr, ChkAccent, 1) = "E"
        Case 204 To 207                      ' 4 x accented I
            Mid(myAltPlyr, ChkAccent, 1) = "I"
        Case 209                             ' 1 x accented N (Ñ)
            Mid(myAltPlyr, ChkAccent, 1) = "N"
        Case 210 To 214                      ' 5 x accented O
            Mid(myAltPlyr, ChkAccent, 1) = "O"
        Case 217 To 220                      ' 4 x accented U
            Mid(myAltPlyr, ChkAccent, 1) = "U"
        Case 138                             ' 1 x accented S (Š)
            Mid(myAltPlyr, ChkAccent, 1) = "S"
'       Case 268                             ' 10C
'           Mid(myAltPlyr, ChkAccent, 1) = "S"
        Case Else
            If Mid(myAltPlyr, ChkAccent, 1) = ChrW(&H10C) Then  '
                Mid(myAltPlyr, ChkAccent, 1) = "C"
            End If
        End Select
    End If
Next
Debug.Print myAltPlyr
```

I have 13,700 rows and 29 columns filled with names.

Comment: Do a loop where you do "Leon", "Léon", "Lèon" etc then consider wildcards.

Comment: How are you currently searching? You mention a filter, do you mean that you populate an autofilter or a filter function, or do you use `Find` in VBA?

Comment: If you use a loop you can do things like `Like L[èeé]on`

Answer (score 3):

There is no "Build-In" function that works as you want.

My suggestion would be to make a "shadow" worksheet (you can set is to hidden) that contains the names without accent characters, umlauts and the like, but with replaced "regular" characters. You need to create and "translate" this sheet only once, so it doesn't matter if that takes some time:

a) Create a sub like this (based on https://www.excelhow.net/replace-accented-characters.html). Check if the lists of special characters is complete. Only drawback: The german sharp-s ("ß") character usually is replaces by "ss" - if you have this (or other characters), add an additional Replace-command.

```
Sub ReplaceAccentedChar(r As Range)
    Const fromChar As String = "ŠŽšžŸÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿ" 
    Const toChar As String = "SZszYAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnooooouuuuyy" 

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(fromChar)
        r.Replace Mid(fromChar, i, 1), Mid(toChar , i, 1), LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=True
    Next i
    r.Replace "ß", "ss", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=True
End Sub
```

b) Create a copy of the sheet holding the names. Name the sheet as you like - I took the name `"Shadow"`.

c) In the immediate window, execute the command

```
 ReplaceAccentedChar ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Shadow").UsedRange
```

d) For the original sheet, add a `Change`-event routine so that the shadow sheet is updated when the original data changes

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range, shadowCell As Range
    For Each cell In Target
        Set shadowCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Shadow").Cells(cell.row, cell.Column)
        shadowCell = cell
        ReplaceAccentedChar shadowCell
    Next
End Sub
```

e) Now comes the tricky part: Set the filter. The following routine will filter only for column A, adapt that (maybe pass the column as extra parameter). It will filter the shadow sheet for a specific string, loop over all filtered cells and read the "real" name from the original sheet. It creates a Dictionary out of it, and this dictionary is used to set the filter to the original sheet.

```
Sub FilterData(filterStr As String)
    If filterStr = "" Then Exit Sub
    ' Set filter on shadow sheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Shadow")
        Dim r As Range
        Set r = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("A:A"))
        r.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=filterStr
        Debug.Print r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address
    End With
    
    ' Create list of "real" names into dictionary
    Dim d As Object, cell As Range
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each cell In r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If cell.row <> 1 Then
            Dim realName As String
            realName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Names").Cells(cell.row, cell.Column)
            d.Add realName, ""
        End If
    Next
    
    ' Filter original sheet using the dictionary
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Names")
        Set r = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("A:A"))
        If d.Count = 0 Then
            ' Nothing found, hide all
            r.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=filterStr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        Else
            r.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=d.keys, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice ideas for a complete solution; a possible way instead of a shadow sheet might be to use comments; I demonstrated a tricky way to convert strings to base letters in a separate post below. @FunThomas

Answer (score 0):

One way could be like this

```
Dim c As Long, mycell As Range
For Each mycell In Range("B:B")
    For c = 1 To Len(mycell.Value)
        If Asc(Mid(mycell.Value, c, 1)) >= 192 Then ' add mode ASC conditions here as needed
            '
            'character found, your code here
            '
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I appreciate that that will find where there is a foreign character, but I was looking for a way of searching using normal text and finding the results whether they contain accents or not (and there are absolutely loads of different ones)...I think it will be difficult without a ream of code to cope with this, as well as slowing the search down to a crawl. Looking for a miracle solution, I guess...

Comment: Perhaps I should expand it a bit...I have currently 13,700 rows and 29 columns filled with names - it's pretty big - that's nearly 400, 000 cells...

Comment: Thanks for all the comments - I managed to overcome it by using a Select Case loop

Comment: For ChkAccent = 1 To Len(myAltPlyr)
       If Asc(Mid(myAltPlyr, ChkAccent, 1)) = 138 Or Asc(Mid(myAltPlyr, ChkAccent, 1)) >= 192 Or Mid(myAltPlyr, ChkAccent, 1) = ChrW(&H10C) Then
       Select Case Asc(Mid(myAltPlyr, ChkAccent, 1))
           Case 192 To 198 'A
               Mid(myAltPlyr, ChkAccent, 1) = "A"
           Case 199 'C with cedilla
               Mid(myAltPlyr, ChkAccent, 1) = "C"
           Case 200 To 203 'E
               Mid(myAltPlyr, ChkAccent, 1) = "E"
           Case 204 To 207 'I
               Mid(myAltPlyr, ChkAccent, 1) = "I"

Comment: Case 209
               Mid(myAltPlyr, ChkAccent, 1) = "N"
           Case 210 To 214
               Mid(myAltPlyr, ChkAccent, 1) = "O"
           Case 217 To 220
               Mid(myAltPlyr, ChkAccent, 1) = "U"
           Case 138
               Mid(myAltPlyr, ChkAccent, 1) = "S"
           Case 268
               Mid(myAltPlyr, ChkAccent, 1) = "S"
           Case Else
               If Mid(myAltPlyr, ChkAccent, 1) = ChrW(&H10C) Then
               Mid(myAltPlyr, ChkAccent, 1) = "C"
            End If
        End Select 
    End If
Next

Comment: Technical questions?

Comment: a) How do you post with all the formatting correctly laid out

Comment: b? How dor you post long bits of code?

Comment: Just enclose code between a start and an end row with a triple ``` @SpencerDudeUK

Answer (score 0):

As OP doesn't reveal too much details, my focus lies upon the **conversion part** to unaccented letters as essential part of a possible solution *(further ideas in addition to @FunThomas ' nice "Shadow Worksheet" approach might be to execute any conversion in comments and to search there)*:

Instead of reading through *all* letters with *all* the accent variations (c.f. [older posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151886/how-to-read-e-%c3%a9-as-the-same-thing-using-search-macro-in-excel/17155284#17155284)), my **tricky alternative** uses the possibilities of the **`Match()`** function together with two helper functions `getABC()` and `Ch2ar()` converting string letters to an array.

This approach allows not only

- to compare an entire `ltr` array *(consisting of letters in a string)* in search for the letter position within a separate **`abc` array** *(consisting of the base letters **"a"** to **"z"**)*, but also
- to match preceding **unaccented base letters** *in one go* by omitting its 3rd argument (or: match type 1):

```
    mtch = Application.Match(ltr, abc)   ' returning the found base positions in abc
```

**Main function `plain()`**

*Time behaviour: It needed roughly 12 seconds to execute the function `plain()` upon 40,000 string values in a datafield array.*

```
Function plain(Optional byval txt As String = "léon") As String
'Purp: Return unaccented base letters A-Za-z
'Note: Match always results in 1-based array
    Dim abc, ltr, mtch
    abc = getABC()              ' assign letters a-z to array abc (including "ß")
    ltr = Ch2Ar(txt)            ' assign each letter of input text to array ltr
    mtch = Application.Match(ltr, abc, 1) ' no 3rd argument finds base letter or MatchType:=1!
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(ltr)    ' loop through letters
        If IsNumeric(mtch(i + 1)) Then
            Dim pos As Long
            pos = mtch(i + 1)
            ltr(i) = IIf(ltr(i) = UCase(ltr(i)), UCase(abc(pos)), abc(pos))
        End If
    Next i
    plain = Join(ltr, "")
    'plain = VBA.replace(plain, "ß", "ss", 1)

End Function
```

**Conversion functions**

```
Function Ch2Ar(ByVal s As String)
'Purp: change a string to array elements
    Dim tmp() As String
    tmp = Split(StrConv(s, vbUnicode), vbNullChar)
    ReDim Preserve tmp(0 To UBound(tmp) - 1)
    Ch2Ar = tmp
End Function
```

```
Function getABC()
'Purp:  return array of lowercase letters a-z
'       (including german "ß" - so called 'sharp s' - after "s")
'Note:  below split-version only valid for Microsoft Excel
    Dim abc
    If Application.Name = "Microsoft Excel" Then
        abc = Split( _
        Join([Char(Column(A:S)+96)], " ") & " ß " & _
        Join([Char(Column(T:Z)+96)], " "))
    Else
        abc = Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", _
        "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "ß", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z")
    End If
    ReDim Preserve abc(1 To 27)
    getABC = abc
End Function
```