# How to create an VBA function in Access to replace any special character in table

Tags: vba, ms-access, replace, character

We import XML files into an Access database. This data includes a description column which can contain special characters like ä é etc. We use this database to export a table to our Financial programm. This programm can't handle these special characters. Therefore I would like to make a VBA function that can replace any special character within a specific table/colomn.

I am fairly new to using VBA, so I used Google a lot to try to find some background about this topic. I have found this code for Excel, and think this can be used in Access as well. However, I can't make the connection with the Update table function.

```
Function RemovePunctuation(Txt As String) As String
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
.Pattern = "[^A-Z0-9 ]"
.IgnoreCase = True
.Global = True
RemovePunctuation = .Replace(Txt, "")
End With
End Function
```

The Function above (RemovePunctuation) works with the Query in Access  and returns a list with the values of the original table without any punctuation. I used the following Query:

```
SELECT RemovePunctuation([ColumnName]) AS [Add]
FROM TableName;
```

However, this returns a new table instead of replacing the values in the original table. Can information be shared on a different Query which uses the function to update originale table?

Cause I'm really new to this, I can't show much. I would expect the code to look like:

```
Function UpdateTable(Table As String, Column As String) As String
Update Table Set Column = 
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
.Pattern = "[^A-Z0-9 ]"
.IgnoreCase = True
.Global = True
RemovePunctuation = .Replace(Txt, "")
End With
End Function
```

But this returns nothing.

Expected result should be returning spaces where special characters are in column selected.

As mentioned, code returns nothing so far as this isn't a valid function at all. Please advise.

Comment: If you want to be non-destructive see: [Excel 2007 VBA Converting Accented Characters to Regular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032322/excel-2007-vba-converting-accented-characters-to-regular)

Comment: Hi,

I have used the stripAccent function from that example in combination with the Query as shown in the edited question. Two questions that follow: 

1. How to update the original table, not show a query result.
2. The function returns E from é, so it messes up capital and not capital letters. How to make that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on code provided by @jeroen jong, the question is answered. Provided code to replace special characters in any given table in Access is the following:

One module is made with the following code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Const strObject As String = "modConversion"

Function ReplaceString(strCaller As String, memText As Variant, strSearch As String, 
strReplace As String) As Variant
On Error GoTo Err_Function

'Define variables
Dim strProcedure    As String       'name of current procedure
Dim dblPos          As Double      'pointer in text

'Initialise variables
strProcedure = "ReplaceString"

'Walk through the text, search and replace
dblPos = InStr(memText, strSearch)
Do While dblPos > 0
   If Asc(strSearch) = Asc(Mid$(memText, dblPos, 1)) Then
      memText = Left$(memText, dblPos - 1) + strReplace + Mid$(memText, dblPos + Len(strSearch))
      dblPos = Abs(dblPos - Len(strSearch))
   End If
   dblPos = InStr(dblPos + 1, memText, strSearch)
Loop

ReplaceString = memText

Exit_Function:
Exit Function

Err_Function:
MsgBox Err.Number, Err.Description, Err.Source, strObject, strProcedure
ReplaceString = memText
Resume Exit_Function

End Function
```

One function is created the call the ReplaceString function. In this case it is called from a Form with a button:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Const strObject As String = "frmReplace"

Private Sub cmdReplace_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Sub

'Define variables
Dim strProcedure    As String       'name of current procedure
Dim dbs             As DAO.Database
Dim rsTable         As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsReplace       As DAO.Recordset
Dim strFieldName    As String

'Initialise variables
strProcedure = "cmdReplace_Click"

'Initialise database and recordset
Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rsReplace = dbs.OpenRecordset("tblReplace", dbReadOnly)

With rsReplace
Do While Not .EOF
   'Open table
   Set rsTable = dbs.OpenRecordset(!TableName, dbOpenDynaset)
   'Walk through all records, and replace char in field
   Do While Not rsTable.EOF
      rsTable.Edit
        rsTable(!FieldName) = ReplaceString(strProcedure, rsTable(!FieldName), !TextSearch, !TextReplace)
      rsTable.Update
      rsTable.MoveNext
   Loop     'rsTable

   .MoveNext
   rsTable.Close
Loop 'rsReplace

.Close
End With

MsgBox "Replacement of special characters is completed", vbInformation, "Replace"

Exit_Sub:
On Error Resume Next
rsTable.Close
Set rsTable = Nothing
rsReplace.Close
Set rsReplace = Nothing
dbs.Close
Set dbs = Nothing

Exit Sub

Err_Sub:
MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & vbLf & Err.Description & " - " & vbLf & Err.Source, vbCritical, strObject & "-" & strProcedure
Resume Exit_Sub

End Sub
```

The table to provide data to search and replace consists of the following columns:

```
Id As Id;
TableName As String;
FieldName As String;
Replace As Boolean;
TextSearch As String;
TextReplace As String;
CaseSensitive As Boolean;
```

Again thanks for solving my question!

Answer (score 0):

In case the xml file is not linked, but indeed imported, you have full control of the imported data. You could create an additional table, where you have a field 'TableName' for each xml file, a field 'FieldName' for each column, a field 'CharIn' for each special character to validate and a field 'CharOut' for the replacing character. Then build code to walk through the imported data, and then search and replace based upon your new additional table. Replace is a default function, but you could write your own, something like

```
Function ReplaceString(strCaller As String, memText As Variant, strSearch As String, strReplace As String) As Variant

'Define variables
Dim dblPos          As Double      'pointer in text

'Walk through the text, search and replace
dblPos = InStr(memText, strSearch)
Do While dblPos > 0
   If Asc(strSearch) = Asc(Mid$(memText, dblPos, 1)) Then
      memText = Left$(memText, dblPos - 1) + strReplace + Mid$(memText, dblPos + Len(strSearch))
      dblPos = Abs(dblPos - Len(strSearch))
   End If
   dblPos = InStr(dblPos + 1, memText, strSearch)
Loop

ReplaceString = memText
```

Comment: Thanks for your example. I just don't see the relationship between the variables in the function you show and the "tempTable" containing the search and replace values. Where does strCaller and memText relate to?

Comment: np, a part of the code and comments are automatically deleted. These are parameters for the function Let's say this procedure is called by a button cmdReplace then the strCaller would be "cmdReplace_Click". This way the proc always knows who's calling. memText is your complete text to be examined, this used to be a memo field, now a variant will do. So if you walk through your table, xetermine the field, en get the text from this field, and then call this proc, using the parameters, it will return the updated text. If you like i can provide complete VBA, but then I need some examples.

Comment: made an [example](http://www.filedropper.com/replace) with two tables as imported tables, replace table with character replacement logic, module with function to replace and form with command to start, hope this helps

Comment: Hi @Jeroen Jong, thank you very much for your example. When I try to open it, I get an error message regarding a broken link to Chillkat 32 bit.dll or something similar. Because of that, I can't test your original file. I have made a new .accdb database and recreated all your coded. When pressing the button in the form, a prompt returns: "Replacement of special characters is completed" but the original tables are not changed. Is this due to the use of openRecordSet? Where is the link to update the original table based on the RecordSet data? dim strFieldName is not used. A lot of questions.

Comment: Hi A, sorry, I should have delete the link to chilkat. .Go to the module, click references and uncheck chilkat.  Otherwise just copy past the tables, form and module in your own clean environment and try again. Should both work

Comment: after deleting the link to chilkat, I was able to test your code. Found out it worked like a charm. It replaces the special characters in tables/columns as specified. Also found the problem in the workbook I recreated, I did a typo and used a - instead off a = in a if statement. Thank you again, kind regards