# Highlight then delete not exactly duplicate items in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I got for example this type of column:
[image: example1]

There are lines of words/phrases where the font is bolded, in capital letters and with accents.

Is there is a way to highlight these not exactly duplicated items then delete the items?

I thought I put all the words on lowercase but then I got a problem with the accents for some words:
[image: example2]

How can I put the missing accents on the bolded words?

At the end I should got something like this:
[image: example3]

and then if I highlight the words:
[image: example4]

and delete them:
[image: final]

This is what I used to "lowercase" the words:

```
Dim Lg%, i%
Lg = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
If Mmi = False Then
    For i = 2 To Lg
        'Cells(i, 1) = UCase(Cells(i, 1)) 'maj
    Next i
    Mmi = True
 Else
    For i = 2 To Lg
        Cells(i, 1) = LCase(Cells(i, 1)) 'min
    Next i
    Mmi = False
End If
```

To remove duplicates I will use something like:

```
Range("A1:A30").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
```

On other hand I thought to take off the accents but I don't know how to do that either.

Comment: It'll be a lot less fuss if you are willing to do this the other way around by changing all accented characters to their non-accented equivalent. Is that a possibility?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032322/how-to-call-a-macro-to-convert-accented-characters-to-regular-that-does-not-ap

Comment: JvdV - Yes I had thought about that too, and to fix after the spelling problems I will pass the entries of the workbook on a corrector, I could have done it by hand but I have more than 15k entries :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at how your data is build (accented strings underneath the non-accented strings), maybe something along these line:

***<sub>Data:</sub>***

[image]

***<sub>Code:</sub>***

```
Sub test()

Dim lr As Long, x As Long, y As Long
Dim arr1 As Variant: arr1 = [TRANSPOSE(MID("àáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿ",ROW(1:28),1))]
Dim arr2 As Variant: arr2 = [TRANSPOSE(MID("aaaaaaceeeeiiiidnooooouuuuyy",ROW(1:28),1))]
Dim str1 As String: str1 = Join(arr1, """,""")
Dim str2 As String
Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With Sheet1'Change according to your sheets CodeName

    'Find your last row and populate array
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arr = .Range("A1:A" & lr)

    'Loop through full array
    For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)

        'Check if any accented characters occur and fill dictionary accordingly
        If .Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({""" & str1 & """},""" & LCase(arr(x, 1)) & """)))") > 0 Then
            str2 = arr(x, 1)
            For y = 1 To 28
                str2 = Replace(str2, arr1(y), arr2(y))
            Next y
            dict(LCase(str2)) = LCase(arr(x, 1))
        Else
            dict(LCase(arr(x, 1))) = LCase(arr(x, 1))
        End If

    Next x

    'Loop through dictionary and do something with unique items
    For Each Key In dict
        Debug.Print dict(Key)
    Next Key

End With

End Sub
```

***<sub>Code:</sub>***

[image]