VBA Code to filter a table and all its columns, whilst typing and ignoring accents
I´m studying interpreting and I want to continue to use Excel as my main tool whilst simultaneous interpreting. I`ve already created a FILTER function and I found a simple VBA Code, that filtered one column of my table/glossary as I typed letters and changed the table to show results (I used a TextBox with a linked cell).
The problem I have is that, I want to filter all columns of my multi-language glossary whilst I type and I need Excel to ignore accents (ä,ü,ö,à...).
Just imagine a simple with multiple columns for different terms in different languages.



Thema
Deutsch
English
French




wirtschaft
wirtschaft
economy
économie


wirtschaft
anlage
asset
atout


sport
rudern
rowing
aviron


sport
volleyball
volleyball
volley-ball


sport
zuschauer
audience
audience


sport
eröffnungszeremonie
opening ceremony
Cérémonie d'ouverture


sport
medaillen
medals
Médailles


health
gesundheit
health, wellbeing
bien-être


health
impfung
vaccine
vaccin


health
krebs
cancer
cancer


health
nadeln
needles
aiguilles


politics
minister
minister
ministre


politik
auschreibung
tender
Soumission à l'appel d'offres


sport
Allgemeiner deutscher Hochschulsportverband
Federation of International Univerisity sports
Fédération Internationale du Sport Universitaire



Any help is deeply appreciated, thank you very much.
As noted before, I used a FILTER function and I am already able to use it to filter all the columns of my glossary, however I think I will need to use VBA to solve the problem of accents (ä,ü,ö,à...) whilst filtering.
FILTER:
=FILTER(Glossary;ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F2;Glossar[Deutsch]))+
         ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F2;Glossary[Englisch]));"no match")

VBA:
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Glossar").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, _
                        Criteria1:= "*" & [B2] & "*", _
                        Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

I know that the VBA Code above just searches the second column, haven`t been able to figure out mulit-column search.

Relevant to your accents requirement - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032322/how-to-call-a-macro-to-convert-accented-characters-to-regular-that-does-not-ap

Add colum(s) to your table with unaccented versions of your words and filter on those.  These extra columns can be hidden

Could you share some relevant sample data using this table markdown generator so we have something to work with. Simply copy e.g. 21 relevant rows (including the headers) of the table into the website's text box, press Submit, press Copy and paste it into your post (question).

I followed your advice and posted an exemplary table/glossary. Any help is deeply apreciated.

Filter on Multiple Columns While Typing into a Listbox


Feel free to download a copy of the working file from my Google Drive.

Sheet Module, e.g. Glossar(Glossar)
Option Explicit

Private Sub GlossarySearchBox_Change()
    FilterByStrippedColumn_Change
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    JoinLanguageColumnsInStrippedColumn_Change Target
End Sub

Standard Module, e.g. Module1
Option Explicit

' Assumptions:
' - The table is never empty.
' - There are at least 2 columns.
' - The last column is the Stripped column.
' - There are only Language columns between the first Language column (incl.)
' - and the Stripped column (excl.).

' Module-Level

' Constants
Private Const GLOSSARY_TABLE_NAME As String = "Glossar"
Private Const GLOSSARY_SEARCH_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "B2"
Private Const GLOSSARY_FIRST_LANGUAGE_COLUMN As Long = 2
Private Const DIACRITICAL_STRING As String = "àáâãäåçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöùúûüýÿ"
Private Const STRIPPED_STRING As String = "aaaaaaceeeeiiiinooooouuuuyy"
Private Const JOIN_DELIMITER As String = "\"
Private Const MINIMUM_CHARACTERS As Long = 2 ' minimally 1
' Variables
Private WasStrippedColumnPopulated As Boolean
        
' Shape Calls
    
Sub ClearSearchCell_Click()
    ClearSearchCell
End Sub
    
Sub ClearStrippedColumn_Click()
    ClearStrippedColumn
End Sub

Sub RebuildStrippedColumn_Click()
    RebuildStrippedColumn
End Sub

' Event Calls

' Called by 'Worksheet_Change'
Sub JoinLanguageColumnsInStrippedColumn_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim trg As Range: Set trg = Intersect(RefLanguageColumns, Target)
    If trg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    JoinLanguageColumnsInStrippedColumn trg
    WasStrippedColumnPopulated = True
    
End Sub

' Called by 'SearchBox_Change'
Sub FilterByStrippedColumn_Change()
    FilterByStrippedColumn
End Sub

' Private Functions
        
Private Function RefTable() As ListObject
    Set RefTable = Glossar.ListObjects(GLOSSARY_TABLE_NAME)
End Function
     
Private Function RefLanguageColumns() As Range
    With RefTable.DataBodyRange
        Set RefLanguageColumns = _
            .Resize(, .Columns.Count - GLOSSARY_FIRST_LANGUAGE_COLUMN) _
            .Offset(, GLOSSARY_FIRST_LANGUAGE_COLUMN - 1)
    End With
End Function

Private Function RefSearchCell() As Range
    Set RefSearchCell = Glossar.Range(GLOSSARY_SEARCH_CELL_ADDRESS)
End Function
        
Private Function GetSearchString() As String
    GetSearchString = LCase(CStr(RefSearchCell.Value))
End Function

' Private Subs

Private Sub ClearSearchCell()
    RefSearchCell.Value = vbNullString ' triggers the SearchBox_Change event
End Sub

Private Sub ClearStrippedColumn()
    Dim lo As ListObject: Set lo = RefTable
    ClearTableFilters lo
    With lo.DataBodyRange
        .Columns(.Columns.Count).ClearContents
    End With
    WasStrippedColumnPopulated = False
End Sub

Private Sub RebuildStrippedColumn()
    Dim lo As ListObject: Set lo = RefTable
    ClearTableFilters lo
    JoinLanguageColumnsInStrippedColumn lo.DataBodyRange
    WasStrippedColumnPopulated = True
End Sub

Private Sub ClearTableFilters(ByVal lo As ListObject)
    With lo
        If .ShowAutoFilter Then ' is turned on
            If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then ' is auto-filtered
                .AutoFilter.ShowAllData ' clear filters
            End If
        Else ' is turned off
            .Range.AutoFilter ' turn on
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub FilterByStrippedColumn()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim lo As ListObject: Set lo = RefTable
        ClearTableFilters lo
        Dim SearchString As String: SearchString = GetSearchString
        If Len(SearchString) >= MINIMUM_CHARACTERS Then
            lo.Range.AutoFilter _
                Field:=lo.ListColumns.Count, _
                Criteria1:="*" & SearchString & "*"
        End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub JoinLanguageColumnsInStrippedColumn(ByVal rg As Range)
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Join Language Columns in Stripped Column"
    
    Dim lrg As Range: Set lrg = Intersect(rg.EntireRow, RefLanguageColumns)
    If lrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim ColumnsCount As Long: ColumnsCount = lrg.Columns.Count
    Dim DelLen As Long: DelLen = Len(JOIN_DELIMITER)
    
    Dim arg As Range, aData() As Variant, r As Long, c As Long, Text As String

    On Error Goto ClearError
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    For Each arg In lrg.Areas
        aData = arg.Value
        For r = 1 To UBound(aData, 1)
            Text = vbNullString
            For c = 1 To ColumnsCount
                Text = Text & aData(r, c) & JOIN_DELIMITER
            Next c
            Text = Left(Text, Len(Text) - DelLen) ' remove trailing delimiter
            StripDiacritics Text
            aData(r, 1) = Text
        Next r
        arg.Columns(1).Offset(, ColumnsCount).Value = aData
    Next arg

ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        WasStrippedColumnPopulated = True
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error [" & Err.Number & "]:" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub

Private Sub StripDiacritics(ByRef Text As String)
    
    Text = LCase(Text)
    
    Dim n As Long, MatchedCharPosition As Long, Char As String
    
    For n = 1 To Len(Text)
        Char = Mid(Text, n, 1)
        MatchedCharPosition = InStr(DIACRITICAL_STRING, Char)
        If MatchedCharPosition > 0 Then
            Text = Replace(Text, _
                Mid(DIACRITICAL_STRING, MatchedCharPosition, 1), _
                Mid(STRIPPED_STRING, MatchedCharPosition, 1))
        End If
    Next n
    
End Sub


Thank you very, very much for your detailed help! Very much appreciated ;-)

Here's something to try without VBA, using named functions:

substitution method is adopted from Diacritical Character to ASCII Character Mapping

define the following in Name Manager






Name
Refers to




acc_1
="ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ"


acc_2
="ĀāĂăĄąĆćĈĉĊċČčĎďĐđĒēĔĕĖėĘęĚěĜĝĞğĠġĢģĤĥĦħĨĩĪīĬĭĮįİıĴĵĶķĸĹĺĻļĽľĿŀŁłŃńŅņŇňŉŊŋŌōŎŏŐőŒœŔŕŖŗŘřŚśŜŝŞşŠšŢţŤťŦŧŨũŪūŬŭŮůŰűŲųŴŵŶŷŸŹźŻżŽžſ"


acc_chars
=acc_1 & acc_2


reg_1
="aaaaaaaceeeeiiiienoooooouuuuypsaaaaaaaceeeeiiiienoooooouuuuypy"


reg_2
="aaaaaaccccccccddddeeeeeeeeeegggggggghhhhiiiiiiiiiijjkkkllllllllllnnnnnnnnnoooooooorrrrrrssssssssttttttuuuuuuuuuuuuwwyyyzzzzzzs"


reg_chars
=reg_1 & reg_2


acc2reg
=LAMBDA(c, IFERROR(MID(reg_chars, FIND(c, acc_chars), 1), NA()))


all2reg
=LAMBDA(term, MAP(term, LAMBDA(term, REDUCE(term, MID(term, SEQUENCE(LEN(term)), 1), LAMBDA(acc,cur, IF(ISNA(acc2reg(cur)), acc, SUBSTITUTE(acc, cur, acc2reg(cur))))))))



Then all2reg can be used anywhere in the workbook - for example enter in F2:
=IFERROR(
    FILTER(
        Glossary,
        MMULT(
            --ISNUMBER(
                SEARCH(all2reg(F2), all2reg(Glossary[[Deutsch]:[French]]))
            ),
            SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(Glossary) - 1, , 1, 0)
        )
    ),
    "no match"
)



Without using Name Manager

substitute accented characters in both search term and language columns
search in all language columns, and get grouped results per row with MMULT function - Microsoft Support

Enter in F2:
=LET(
    acc_1, "ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ",
    acc_2, "ĀāĂăĄąĆćĈĉĊċČčĎďĐđĒēĔĕĖėĘęĚěĜĝĞğĠġĢģĤĥĦħĨĩĪīĬĭĮįİıĴĵĶķĸĹĺĻļĽľĿŀŁłŃńŅņŇňŉŊŋŌōŎŏŐőŒœŔŕŖŗŘřŚśŜŝŞşŠšŢţŤťŦŧŨũŪūŬŭŮůŰűŲųŴŵŶŷŸŹźŻżŽžſ",
    acc_chars, acc_1 & acc_2,
    reg_1, "aaaaaaaceeeeiiiienoooooouuuuypsaaaaaaaceeeeiiiienoooooouuuuypy",
    reg_2, "aaaaaaccccccccddddeeeeeeeeeegggggggghhhhiiiiiiiiiijjkkkllllllllllnnnnnnnnnoooooooorrrrrrssssssssttttttuuuuuuuuuuuuwwyyyzzzzzzs",
    reg_chars, reg_1 & reg_2,
    acc2reg, LAMBDA(c, IFERROR(MID(reg_chars, FIND(c, acc_chars), 1), NA())),
    all2reg, LAMBDA(term,
        MAP(
            term,
            LAMBDA(term,
                REDUCE(
                    term,
                    MID(term, SEQUENCE(LEN(term)), 1),
                    LAMBDA(acc, cur, IF(ISNA(acc2reg(cur)), acc, SUBSTITUTE(acc, cur, acc2reg(cur))))
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    IFERROR(
        FILTER(
            Glossary,
            MMULT(
                --ISNUMBER(SEARCH(all2reg(F2), all2reg(Glossary[[Deutsch]:[French]]))),
                SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(Glossary) - 1, , 1, 0)
            )
        ),
        "no match"
    )
)


adding helper columns as suggested by chris neilsen might improve performance, if your lists are long and many.


I want to thank you for the help. Now I have two different approaches to solve my problem :-)

would it be possible to upload your Excel Workbook with your first solution? I find yours to be much simpler for my needs, however I cant quite seem to make it work. I immediatly get 0 or "no match". Im very sorry for the inconveniece.

I`ve downloaded the file. I will lookup what Im doing wrong. Thank you.

still cant really say what is wrong with my excel sheet when I do it, but Ill figure it out (I often get a message about corruption after reopening the file). Thank you again for your valuable help. I really appreciate it.

Not very large, about 135 entered terms with three columns (again germen, english, french). I post the terms in your file, it works just fine. It has to be a problem on my end.

Ah, yes - amount of data won't be a problem. Hope you figure it out- will be a good exercise ;)
